horror movie - woman at a party has a pimple, and bugs crawl out of it
I'm looking for a stupid American horror film I probably saw in the 1980's. There is just one scene I remember:  a woman is at a party, and she has a pimple.  She keeps putting pressed powder makeup on it, not knowing that someone has sprinkled something evil on her pressed powder. The culmination (if you could call it that) is that a bunch of bugs come crawling out of her zit.
Any ideas what cheesy movie that was? In my mind I'm mixing it up with another stupid horror movie with Martin Sheen whose wife died by electrocution, and he tries to get her back using voodoo or something.  They might be the same movie, but they might not be.  My question is really only about the woman with the bug-zit.

The Martin Sheen movie you mentioned where the wife dies of electrocution is The Believers from 1987:

After the death of his wife, police psychiatrist Cal Jamison moves to New York. There he has to help in the investigation of the murder of two youths, who seem to have been immolated during a cult ritual. Jamison believes it's been Voodoo and, ignoring the warnings of his housekeeper, enters the scenery and soon gets under their influence. They try to get him to sacrifice his own son. 

And it does contain a scene where spiders come out of a woman's pimple (WARNING, GORY):




That's the movie! My memory was right -- it was that Martin Sheen flick.

BTW, I think it's funny that she (1) knocks the light so it's swinging and spooky, and then (2) spills the marbles and sort of spreads them around with her hand.

At least she didn't try to spell HELP. :P

Yep. Would have taken too long. LOL!
